# AngularJS directive Passing parameters to isolated scope function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I wrote a directive that displays one button for each product passed to the directive. The product should also be passed to the function `subscribe` of the directive when the button is clicked.

The issue I have is that the parameter is not passed to the function.

**The directive**

```
directives.directive('subscriptionItem', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            // Two way binding, = is equivalent to '=activeSubscription'
            activeSubscription: '=',
            products: '=',
            googleLogin: '&',
            subscribe: '&'
        },
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: 'true',
        templateUrl: 'common/directives/subscription-item.tpl.html'
    };
});
```

**The template**

```
<div>
    <ion-item class="item-text-wrap">
        <h2>{{activeSubscription.status}} - {{activeSubscription.action}}</h2>

        <p>{{activeSubscription.description}}</p>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item ng-repeat="product in products" class="item-text-wrap" ng-if="activeSubscription.action === 'PAID'">
        <h2>{{product.title | limitTo: product.title.length - 21}}</h2>

        <p>{{product.description}}</p>
        <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="subscribe(product.productId)">
            Buy for {{product.price}} - {{product.productId}}
        </button>
    </ion-item>
</div>
```

The `product.productId` is correctly displayed but not passed to the function.

**The directive usage**

```
<subscription-item active-subscription="activeSubscription" products="products" google-login="googleLogin()" subscribe="subscribe(sku)"></subscription-item>
```

The subscribe function in the parent controller scope

```
$scope.subscribe = function (sku) {
    console.log('subscribe ' + sku)
    InAppBillingService.subscribe(sku)
        .then(function () {
            console.log('Success');
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            $cordovaToast.showLongBottom(error);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to pass make data available as a variable within the expression referred to by the `subscribe` attribute, which in your case is `subscribe(sku)`, you need to supply a "locals map", when calling the function inside the directive:

```
    <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="subscribe({sku: product.productId})">
        Buy for {{product.price}} - {{product.productId}}
    </button>
```

Now, when you have the variable `sku` in the `subscribe` attribute expression wherever you use that directive, it will have the value of the productId, which will then work.

Relevant section from [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile):

> Often it's desirable to pass data from the isolated scope via an
>   expression to the parent scope, this can be done by passing a map of
>   local variable names and values into the expression wrapper fn. For
>   example, if the expression is increment(amount) then we can specify
>   the amount value by calling the localFn as localFn({amount: 22}).

Comment: This is what I get in the log: `Object {sku: undefined}`. `product.productId` seems not to be interpreted. Using the method from Joe, it seems to work.

Comment: I verified my solution worked [in this Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/nIllV554pHMBlqzAV6Pd?p=preview). I tried with both AngularJS version 1.3.14 and version 1.4.0-beta.5. Double check you have made all the changes I suggested, and that you are using single curly brackets, not double inside the `ng-click` expression.

Answer (score 1):

& creates a function in your directive that returns the result of the expression after evaluation against the parent scope.

An easy fix would be to change your template to:

```
<button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="subscribe()(product.productId)">
        Buy for {{product.price}} - {{product.productId}}
</button>
```

And usage to

```
<subscription-item active-subscription="activeSubscription" products="products" google-login="googleLogin()" subscribe="subscribe"></subscription-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you know there are 3 AngularJs Directive scope methods: '@', '=', '&', but now we are going to talk about only '&' method.We are going to see , how we can implement method '&' in our applications.

When we define any function inside current scope and want to implement it to any directives,Remember one thing: you have to pay attention on your function's arguments and their order.If you want more,here is a great article about that:

http://www.w3docs.com/snippets/angularjs/angularjs-directive-scope-method.html